# F-score is ill-defined scikit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision, precision-recall

I know this question has been asked many times but I am confused about this warning because I am still getting the f1score. For me, it's not zero.

I have calculated f1score for micro and it works fine there is no warning. but when I am calculating f1score for macro then it is giving me a warning. I am getting the precision score and recall as well. Both are not zero. they are very less for example 0.01 or 0.001 sometimes. and same with f1score it's not zero as well. But I am not sure that why I am getting this warning. As I have read in other posts that this might be that you are diving 0/0 because precision or recall is zero. But in my case, I have some value rather than zero.

Here is the exact warning:

```
UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
```

**So can I rely on the result and avoid the warning?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f1_score` with `average='macro'` will first calculate score for each label individually, and then find their unweighted mean.

So it may happen that if you have multiple classes (labels), then one of them is not present in the predicted data. In that case, you will get the warning for that (absent) label and f1 will be 0 for that. But other labels will still have some non-zero value. So the mean will be non-zero.

For example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
y_pred = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
```

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.

```
# Output:  0.38888888888888884
```

In the above example, the predicted data doesnot contain the label 2, and the warning is for that.

Now, about the question as to rely on that or not, please see the related questions:

- https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/15989/41018
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/156923/133411